# Android, How to retrieve redirect URL from a WebView?

Tags: android, webview

First i surfed the web but no answer was found matching my case.
I want to grab a specific redirect url from a webview and then keep the webview from opening it. The case is an Instagram redirect url after the user authorized my app. How to do it? Here is my code:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=my_client_id&redirect_uri=my_redirect_uri&response_type=code");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally thanks to the answer given to my question by Udi I, with a little change, i managed to find a solution to the problem. Here is the code which worked for me:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wView, String url) {
               return (url.indexOf("some part of my redirect uri") > -1);                               
        }       
    });
    webView.loadUrl(myUrl); //myUrl is the initial url.
```

Using the above code, if there will be any url containing redirect uri, webView won't load it. Else, webView will load it. Also thanks to Kamil Kaminski.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to set your custom WebviewClient overriding shouldOverrideUrlLoading method for your webview before loading the url.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)
        {
            return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(url);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request)
        {
            Uri uri = request.getUrl();
            return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(uri.toString());
        }

        private boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final String url)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading() URL : " + url);

            // Here put your code

            return true; // Returning True means that application wants to leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.
        }
    });

mWebView.loadUrl("Your URL");
```

> Checkout the example code for handling redirect urls and open PDF without download, in webview.
>   https://gist.github.com/ashishdas09/014a408f9f37504eb2608d98abf49500

Answer (score 2):

You should override shouldOverrideUrlLoading:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wView, String url) {

               if (url.indexOf('api.instagram.com') > -1) //check if that's a url you want to load internally
               {
                    webView.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
               }
               else
               {
                    return false; //Let the system handle it
               }                
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set `WebViewClient` for your `WebView`, and override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` in `WebViewClient`. In that method you can grab your url, and decide whether or not your `WebView` should follow redirection url. Here's example:

```
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // here you can assign parameter "url" to some field in class

            // return true if you want to block redirection, false otherwise
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare URL strings / particular word, and take actions accordingly -

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);

if (url.contains(".pdf")
openPDF(url); // handle pdf opening

if(url.startsWith("tel:")
callNumber(url); // handle call processing
...
}
```

Just to add more, you can prevent webview from showing traditional error message screens, or bypass known errors -

```
 @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                        String description, String failingUrl) {
                    if (errorCode == -10) {
                        System.out.println("Error occured: Error code: "
                                + errorCode + "..Ignoring this error");
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     // Show your custom screen to notify error has occured
                    }
    ...
    }
```