# Azure AD 2.0 oauth does not redirect

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-ad-graph-api

We are attempting to authenticate an app (built in Xamarin,iOS) and we cannot get the oath to redirect to the success url. It successfully registers the app to the user (and appears in their my account on portal.office.com) but it never redirects to give us an access token. It works in the web browser on my laptop just not on the phone.

We even tested using microsoft's example (shown below) and this also does not redirect. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc- 
6eba6914391e&response_type=id_token+token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&scope=openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
```

We spoke to Microsoft and they claim there is no issue, and told us to post here instead. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I believe you should be using authorization grant flow for iOS apps.  For implicit grant flow you need a browser

Comment: @VenkateshMarepalli it should work, we are using a webview, the documentation claims it works for mobile applications

Comment: Do you see any error message? Or just no redirect

Comment: @VenkateshMarepalli no errors just no redirect it's really strange

Comment: I guess your webview was not handling the redirect, Could you test any other url and see if redirect is working on your webview, if not you need to update your webview settings to handle the redirects

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871641/android-how-to-retrieve-redirect-url-from-a-webview/42433654

Comment: @VenkateshMarepalli yes I have tried using a different oauth link and it does redirect, just this one doesn't